# Spring namespace handler to create multiple beans

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to create a namespace handler that creates more than one bean. I've been reading the documentation and sample code here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/extensible-xml.html

But that only describes binding one bean to one custom tag. I want something more like this:

```
<myns:drag-in-my-library-beans handler="appHandler" />
```

That results in the creation of lets say 4 beans from the library code, some of which need to make use of appHandler. Is this possible? I think the typical thing spring does for tags like this is:

```
<context:annotation-driven />
```

So insight on how that tag works internally might be helpful.

Comment: Your documentation reference is way out of date.  Spring 2.0.x is very old. The newer docs may be better.

Comment: I looked at the 3.x and the colors have changed but not much else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have missed this line: "BeanDefinition parse(Element, ParserContext) - called when Spring encounters a top-level element (not nested inside a bean definition or a different namespace). This method can register bean definitions itself and/or return a bean definition."

The "register bean definitions itself" would allow you to create an arbitrary number of beans from parsing a single element. See the [parse() javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandler.html#parse%28org.w3c.dom.Element,%20org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.ParserContext%29) for more detail.